# How do I get my Shopify App from my local dev server to their server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, shopify-app

First off, I'm really, really sorry if this has been asked before, but I did not find a satisfying answer. This step seems missing / unthreatened in literally all explanations and tutorials out there.

I've read literally everything about making a Shopify App and I've built one and it works. I'm in the stage of submitting it, but I discovered the project directory is about 40k+ files large. When debugging the App, I ran the test server over ngrok over my local laptop, but it's kind of self explaining that I won't keep it running there 24/7 for the next 50 years.

After reading all guides, I still lack in one important information.
How is my app being pushed/pulled/deployed to their server? What exactly do I do to achieve this, and furthermore, how do I update bugfixes afterwards?

I am aware there is a review process and everything, the question is, when and how does my local app version move over to their servers. exactly?

I was really not able to find satisfying answers to this.

Help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have to host your application on your own server be it a Public app or Custom app.

**Public APP**

1. They will review the approach not the code, they can't see your code,
   it's deployed on your server.
2. In shopify developer account open create public app form, add your    app urls.
3. Submit your app for approval.

**Custom APP**

1. They won't review anything, just deploy your app on your server and
   add your links in the custom app form.